# Java Scanner doesn't read

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to download a file that contains an integer from a remote machine, increase the value of the integer locally, write the new value to the same file and upload the file. I use scp. It downloads the file successfully. I use shell file for downloading and uploading processes. But I have problems with `Scanner`.

**Here is the code:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class shell {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/ayyuce/Desktop/download.sh");
        File f= new File("/home/ayyuce/Desktop/yeni.txt");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);
        Scanner s= new Scanner(f);
        int num=0;
        if(s.hasNextLine()){
            num=s.nextInt();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
        int increase=num++;
        pw.println(increase);

        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/ayyuce/Desktop/upload.sh");
        s.close();
        pw.close();
    }
}
```

The output is: `Error`

I wonder what is the problem with `Scanner`.

Thank you so much!

Comment: `int increase=num++;` will not do what you intended to

Comment: You have your `if-else` block set up so that when the scanner doesn't have another line it will print error

Comment: Also your programm is failing, because the file isn't downloaded when you call `s.hasNextLine()`

Comment: Debug. [link](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @GBlodgett if I delete the if-else if block, I get java.util.NoSuchElementException error.

Comment: No it is correct to check to make sure that the scanner has a next line to scan. I was saying that eventually it will run out of things to scan, and it will go to the else statement and print error. Try removing just the else part

Comment: try using \\ in your file path and inspite of if-else block try while loop.

Comment: @JAMSHAIDIQBAL It doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);

From [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter(java.io.File))

> file - The file to use as the destination of this writer. **If the
>   file exists then it will be truncated to zero size;** otherwise, a new
>   file will be created. The output will be written to the file and is
>   buffered.

Of course, `Scanner` can't read anything, because the file was truncated to zero size in `new PrintWriter(f)`.